# how to show alert when user scroll to top of div in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

hello could you please how to show alert when  scroll to top of div in angular js and same in when user scroll to bottom .Actually I know How to achieve this in jquery using   if(this.scrollTop===0).But I am using ionic framework with angular js .So could could you please tell me how to get event when user scroll to top and show the alert .

here is my plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/8bqDi69oiBKTpDvCaOf6?p=preview

```
<body ng-controller="MyController">
<div style="width:90%;height:150px;border:1px solid red;overflow:auto;overflow-y: scroll">
<div ng-repeat="n in name">{{n.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angular will not provide you anything for this, you just need to bind a scroll event on your element.
In my current project I have just created an event in my controller :

```
var container = angular.element(document);
container.on('scroll', function() {
    if (container.scrollTop() > 1000) {
        $('#scroll-top-button').addClass('show');
    } else {
        $('#scroll-top-button').removeClass('show');
    }
});
// in your case angular.element(document) should be your div instead of document
```

It does perform very well (I would expect a `if` on scroll event to cost some ressource but not really).

### Angular directive

Easy way is to define a directive to bind a scroll event and look at position. Based on your code :

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
  .directive("scrollable", function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var container = angular.element(element);
      container.bind("scroll", function(evt) {
          if (container[0].scrollTop <= 0) {
              alert('On the top of the world I\'m singing I\'m dancing.');
          }
          if (container[0].offsetHeight + container[0].scrollTop >= container[0].scrollHeight) {
              alert('On the bottom of the world I\'m waiting.');
          }
      });
    };
  })
  .controller('MyController', function($scope, $element) {
    $scope.name = [{ ... }];
  });
```

Then in your HTML just add the directive

```
<div scrollable style="width:90%;height:1...
```

I updated a version [on your plunker (v5)](http://plnkr.co/edit/9w7ruITtcKW4LXN1w6jX?p=preview) which work for me and seems pretty strong for global compatibility. Did it low level ;)

### Alternative library

If you want to implement some deeper feature you can use a library like [waypoint](https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints)

> Waypoints is a library that makes it easy to execute a function
>   whenever you scroll to an element.
>   http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/

It works really well too, is very light, and since v3.0 is jQuery free :D. I know some hardcore front-end designer using it without any performance issue.

Comment: could you please tell me on plunker

Comment: can you bind element and show the alert of top and bottom

Comment: Yes you can but I have an issue with your plunker ... angular variable is not define ... working on it and trying to provide an exemple, should be easy :)

Comment: Do you have jQuery in your project ? Would make it easy by using selector :D. If not we might need to write a directive ...

Comment: I don't use jquery in my project ..!! could yoy please write directive

Comment: any idea  ? can we do in angular js using directive ?

Comment: I updated your plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/9w7ruITtcKW4LXN1w6jX?p=preview) and also my answer. You now have a working exemple but will not be able to do more for you :) Hope it will help.

Comment: Thank for help .!!! but can we add alert when user scroll to bottom ,you awser is correct for top can we add for bottom also ?

Comment: I updated my post and your plunker with a bottom event ... google give me the answer in few second you should have tried harder :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a directive so that you connect your element to the backend.

I created a directive which is pretty similar to sebastionbarbier one without the bind part but I guess using link is doing pretty much the same as bind.

```
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
element.on('scroll', function() {
  if(element[0].scrollTop == 0)
   alert('show alert');
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ra6HLvEsPBPHeNqVVI4c?p=preview

Comment: Be careful about `if (element[0].scrollTop == 0` I had some surprise with iPhone/iPad/Mac since scrolling is smooth only every 2/3 pixels and can be negative (you can scroll the page down it will automatically scroll back to zero but not trigger it) so it is better to use `<= 0` :D

Comment: but how to get event when user is at bottom ?

Comment: you know that you are on bottom by using 'if(element[0].scrollTop <= element[0].scrollHeight)'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not disagreeing with the other answers, but you should try not to use any global function in Angular, e.g. `alert()`; you should try to inject dependencies.

Instead, use `$window.alert`, by injecting `$window` into your directive. You can then unit test the behaviour by, for example, using Jasmine's `spyOn($window, "alert")`. E.g.:

```
spyOn($window, "alert");
expect($window.alert).toHaveBeenCalled();
```